# Arduino subtracting chars from strings

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, string

Hello I have an Arduino programme that has a string with the words hello in it. 
I can add characters and other strings to the end of that one using:

```
   String test = "hello";
   test+=" jack";
```

it would then say "hello jack"
The problem is I want to get rid of the last character of the string every 2 seconds so it would be "hello jac" then "hello ja" and so on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [remove()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringRemove) method to remove last character.

```
String s = "1234567890";
while(s.length() > 0) {
    int lastIndex = s.length() - 1;
    s.remove(lastIndex);
    Serial.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Could you please include an example to your answer?

Comment: @Avamander Example provided. :)

Comment: Two typos there: `Sstring` and `lenght`.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to get rid of the last character of the string every 2 seconds so it would be "hello jac" then "hello ja" and so on. How can I do this?

This is how you could do that. Avoid using String and putting the string constants in program memory.

```
// A buffer for the message
const size_t MSG_MAX = 16;
char msg[MSG_MAX];

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
}

void loop()
{
  static int len = 0;
  // Check if it is time to create the initial message
  if (len == 0) {
    strcpy_P(msg, (const char*) F("hello"));
    strcat_P(msg, (const char*) F(" jack"));
    len = strlen(msg) - 1;
  }
  // Otherwise shorten the message
  else {
    msg[len--] = 0;
  }
  // And print current message
  Serial.println(msg);
  delay(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are best of learning about C-style strings rather than the String class. The String class can eventually fragment dynamic memory.

To shorten a string a simple method is to move the "string terminator" inwards by overwriting the last byte of the message with zero, like this:

```
const size_t MSG_MAX = 20;
char msg [MSG_MAX];

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  strcpy (msg, "hello");  // initial message
  strcat (msg, " jack");  // concatenate more stuff
  }  // end of setup

  void loop ()
    {
    if (strlen (msg) > 0)
      {
      Serial.println (msg);  // display current message
      msg [strlen (msg) - 1] = 0;  // move null-terminator in
      delay (1000);
      }  // end of any message left

    }  // end of loop
```

Results:

```
hello jack
hello jac
hello ja
hello j
hello 
hello
hell
hel
he
h
```